# Tips for using vim as a log viewer

Tags: vim, gvim, logging, vimrc

As a log viewer, which of vim's features are convenient?

`less -F` is quite good.
But I believe vim could be better if we knew its hidden features.

> * or #
>   v//d
>   g//d
>   etc..

PS. I don't use vim as a code writing tool.

Comment: It is well known that, we developers, never analyse million lines of log, that we never need a rich tool for that purpose in our development process. I guess that the reason why this post was migrated from SO...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This probably goes without saying but if you're using log files that are overwritten regularly,  then you'll want to:

```
:set autoread
```

so vim will keep the latest log up on screen at all times.

Comment: Yes, I know the option. But the option never works at my machine(Both Windows and linux). Do you know why?

Comment: I run it through gvim under WinXP & it picks up the file changes when the window receives focus (e.g. when alt-tabbing back).  I'm not sure how it works on the CLI but there's a bit more info in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490227/how-does-vims-autoread-work

Answer (score 4):

What makes it convenient? You've got all the [power of vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95072/what-are-your-favorite-vim-tricks), of course ...
I could recommend the [LargeFile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) plugin, though, such that vim doesn't slow down for large log files.

I use vim to search through large log files, using regexps, and sometimes for specific keywords with *, or sometimes create a copy by selecting only specific lines (e.g. `:v//delete`), and using block select to get some specific columns in the log output (since log lines mostly follow a specific format). Easiest way to create a quick table, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the only thing more you're going to get out of using vim as a pager is syntax highlighting if there is a syntax file for the particular log/file you're viewing. You can try out this sh script which does exactly that:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1723

Although it lacks some of less's built in and useful features such as -F, it's not surprising considering vim was designed to be a text editor not a pager.

Comment: I've applied at my machine. But why doesn't vimpager read automatically a dynamic file?

Answer (score 2):

For long lines (not only in log files) scrolling horizontally is convenient. From my ~/.vimrc :

```
"-----------------------------------------------------------
" scroll horizontally     {{{2
"-----------------------------------------------------------
nnoremap <M-Left>  zH
nnoremap <M-Right> zL
inoremap <M-Left>  <Esc>zHi
inoremap <M-Right> <Esc>zLa
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try [the LogViewer plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4156) for viewing multiple parallel log files. While you can use tmux and tail to have a terminal display multiple log files, you won't have your cursor synchronized between the different panes.